# How to update all bigquery tables which contains column and who values matches specific value?

Tags: google-bigquery

We have list of datasets,have to update all tables in dataset that contains specific columns and that column matches specific value

`Select CONCAT('UPDATE  'db.data.', table_name, "' set col1='colvalue' where value=513") From 'db.data.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS; Where column_name in ('ABC','PQR') group by table_name having count(column_name)=2`

Comment: Have you considered using [BigQuery Client Libraries](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/libraries#using_the_client_library) for these?

Comment: Please consider BigQuery scripting, `execute immediate` statement in loop.  [Scripting statements in Standard SQL](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/scripting#execute_immediate)

Comment: @Chandra is it possible to do it in sql query itself ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used scripting in BigQuery

```sql
    # varible to hold list of tables
    DECLARE list_of_tables ARRAY<STRING>;

    # variable to hold count of tables
    DECLARE no_of_tables INT64;

    # varible used in looping
    DECLARE i INT64 DEFAULT 0;  
    
    # get the list of tables which contain column_name in ("ABC","PQR") in the dataset of a project
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE
    'SELECT ARRAY(SELECT table_name FROM `project_name.dataset_name.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` WHERE column_name IN ("ABC","PQR") GROUP BY table_name)'
    INTO list_of_tables;
    
    # setting tables counts from the list_of_tables
    SET no_of_tables =  ARRAY_LENGTH(list_of_tables);
    
    # looping through list of tables and updating them.
    LOOP
        IF i = no_of_tables THEN 
        LEAVE; 
        END IF;
        
        # executing update command
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE
        CONCAT('UPDATE `project_name.dataset_name.',list_of_tables[offset(i)],'` SET col1="colvalue" WHERE value=513');
    
        SET i = i + 1;
    END LOOP
```

Reference:
[Creating Array from subqueries in BigQuery](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/arrays#creating_arrays_from_subqueries)
[Accessing array elements](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/arrays#accessing_array_elements)
[Scripting in BigQuery](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/scripting)
[INFORMATION_SCHEMA.columns](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/information-schema-tables#columns_view)